# How to exclude normal pages from wp search results

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress blog I have, just like anyone else, posts and normal pages.

How do I exclude the normal pages from the search results I get when submitting the wp search form?

Say I have a post and a page both containing the word "foo".

How do I get the search results for "foo" to only list the post?

Comment: Have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140664/custom-search-query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query to only search in 'post' post type. Add this in your functions.php

(*Note: Requires PHP 5.3+*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_search() ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pieter Goosen's answer is ok, but limits the search query results to post type `post`. Here's another approach that modifies the page post type's `exclude_from_search` property and leaves other potentially queried post types intact:

```
add_action( 'init', 'so27342745_exclude_from_search' );
function so27342745_exclude_from_search()
{
    global $wp_post_types;

    $wp_post_types['page']->exclude_from_search = true;
}
```